Is wage-based employment illegal?
EDIT: As Mr. Hall has pointed out, I should probably clarify a couple things.

Wage slavery is suborning your will to that of another in exchange for compensation on a more or less at-will basis (similar to bondservice, in which you do so for a specified period.) In other words, a salaried or wage-based job.

Yes, I am aware that outright banning wage slavery would be absurd, since pretty much all employment is based off of it. Nevertheless, the 13th Amendment would appear to do so when read literally.

Therefore, my question is, what legislation and stare decisis limit the 13th's application to only chattel slavery? I would prefer something more concrete than "that's obviously what the writers intended."

I am not pro-chattel slavery, nor do I seek the outright abolition of wage-based employment.



Original question text:
The 13th Amendment established that:

Neither slavery nor involuntary servitude, except as a punishment for crime whereof the party shall have been duly convicted, shall exist within the United States, or any place subject to their jurisdiction.

The people who wrote it obviously meant to abolish the despicable practice of chattel slavery. However, this is not the only type of slavery; for example, most US jobs are some form of wage slavery (in the technical sense of the term.) The Amendment does not qualify what kind of slavery it forbids, other than an exception for bondslavery as a punishment for crime.
Taken literally, it seems to forbid wage slavery (especially considering how it lists involuntary servitude as a separate category from slavery.) Is this correct? If so, why is wage slavery still the primary form of employment in America?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Wage-based employment is not illegal. It is the most common form of employment in the United States. It does not amount to slavery, "involuntary servitude" or an incident of slavery as conveyed by the 13th Amendment.
You say that the 13th Amendment "does not qualify what kind of slavery it forbids." It did not need to, for the country had just fought a civil war over the issue. There was and is no question as to what kind of slavery the 13th Amendment is about. It is not about wage-based employment.
In fact, the Congress at the time understood the right to enter into contracts of employment as one of the rights that the 13th Amendment sought to secure for the formerly enslaved.
As described by the Court in the Civil Rights Cases,

The long existence of African slavery in this country gave
us very distinct notions of what it was, and what were its
necessary incidents. Compulsory service of the slave for the
benefit of the master, restraint of his movements except by the
master's will, disability to hold property, to make contracts, to
have a standing in court, to be a witness against a white person, and such like burdens and incapacities, were the inseparable
incidents of the institution. Severer punishments for crimes
were imposed on the slave than on free persons guilty of the
same offences. Congress, as we have seen, by the Civil Rights'
Bill of 1866, passed in view of the Thirteenth Amendment,
before the Fourteenth was adopted, undertook to wipe out
these burdens and disabilities, the necessary incidents of slavery,
constituting its substance and visible form; and to secure to all
citizens of every race and color, and without regard to previous
servitude, those fundamental rights which are the essence of civil
freedom, namely, the same right to make and enforce contracts,
to sue, be parties, give evidence, and to inherit, purchase, lease,
sell and convey property, as is enjoyed by white citizens.


In other words: while the 13th Amendment uses a general term, trying to apply it to anything but chattel slavery (or something functionally identical) would be understood as going against the "spirit of the law"?
